# Why the properties of default prop object are empty - React

Tags: reactjs

I need define a default prop that is an object, but this object that have many properties is empty.

I have this Component

```
class User extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    isAdmin: false,
    user: {
      name: 'Husdady',
      age: 20,
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log('[props]', this.props)
  
    return (
      <span>users</span>
    )
  }
}
```

The prop `user` is empty when I set as default prop but when I pass a value in component `User`, this props is not empty, this props have a valid value when I pass a value as `user={user}`.

I don't understand this behaviour. I hope you understand me, I am practice my english, I am Spanish speaker

Comment: Your code looks valid. Are you using your component like `<User />`? Make sure you're not passing a prop that can conflict with your default one (for testing purposes). Check if you import `Component` from `import { Component } from 'react'`. Or restart a server...

Comment: What I want to understand is why React, I return an empty object when I define an object nested in a defaultProp. When is not an object nested in a defaultProp, for example, a string, number, boolean, not problem

Comment: Nested objects are returned to me empty when I set them to defaultProp

Comment: Could you reproduce your error using https://codesandbox.io/? Or add more details to your question to see the problem. Currently, there are no problems with your code. At least I can't see...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-http-rk4uvo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have tried CodeSandbox and I have no such problem, which is blowing my mind. The doubt is that when defining defaultProps, I define a user property to which I assign a name and an age. Well, now when making a console.log of the props, user is an empty object.

Comment: When I run the code in CodeSandbox this problem does not appear, surely maybe I am doing something wrong and this is not the real problem, because I need to have a default user that has properties and is not an empty object